# Which software can implement the function of virtualbox and have other functions?

Tags: virtual-machine

I noticed that there is a software which can have the function of Filezilla and code editor, and work like as a virtual box. It contains many useful features. Could anyone recommend the name of such software?

Comment: Can you describe more detail?